# Do I need to convert my java application to an applet to post it on a webpage?

Tags: java, lwjgl

Is it possible to post a java application on a website without converting it into an applet?
 I have worked hard on making a game and I want to share it. My game uses the Light Weight Java Game Library, so it is harder to convert to an applet. It is currently an application and
I would not like to start all over again making it an applet....

If I do need to convert it into an applet, Could I still use most of the code?

Answer (score 3):

**You won't require much changes if you deploy it as a Java Web Start.**

I'd strongly recommend [looking into this table](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javawebstart.html#APPLETSVSJWS) that clearly shows the differences between both Java Applications, Java Applets and Java Web Start Applications.